# Draw security pattern on Android view with Appium

Tags: android, ui-automation, appium, android-uiautomator

I've a following problem :

[image]

The control is view , it has a "dots" on it (generated during the run time).
I need to draw a security pattern ...

Is it possible to find the view element, and somehow to click "on it" by given location ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution , need to use TouchAction class

```
TouchAction obj = new TouchAction(driver);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TouchAction obj = new TouchAction(driver);
    obj.press(PointOption.point(551,1238)).moveTo(PointOption.point(545, 1019)).release().perform();
```

use this method to swipe  ,it worked for me  for pattern (5,2)